# What methods can be used for tractable computation of probabilities for evolutionary model of non-independent entities?

Tags: stochastic-processes, independence

I'm trying to extend a simple model which works as follows.

We have n 'original' entities which each have a colour. This population evolves by the following events, which occur at exponential rates:

- an entity gives birth to a child entity (of a random colour drawn from some known distribution)
- an entity dies
- an entity changes colour

The end result is a group of *families*, each consisting of at most one (0 if it's dead) original entities and possibly some descendents of that entity.

The problem if we're given the original population of entities and an end population of entities, and want to figure out the likelihood of one evolving into the other (we aren't given the "family structure" of the second group).

This is solved using the trick of noticing that the fate of each original entity is independent. So given a family structure (assigning each original entity to a set in the descendant group, indicating which descendent entity corresponds to the original entity), we need to know just how to calculate the probability of one original entity evolving into one descendent family. Then we do this calculation n times and multiply.

But if we extend this with the possibility that an entity can switch what family it's in, we lose this option and the probabilities get a lot more complicated.

Are there any known good methods for dealing with a case like this of an evolutionary model of several entities whose evolutionary paths are not independent?

Comment: This is very unclear to me.  How is family defined? Is it based on parent/child relationship, i.e., descent, or based on colour?  How does an entity switch families?  if color does not affect family, then what significance, if any, does colour have? How is the end population of entities defined? Is the original population of entities defined just by the number of entities, or do other attributes such as colour come into play? There's a huge literature on use of Markov Chains and variants and other stochastic processes being used in population evolution and mutations and related areas.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is an epidemic model. Something like SIR, SEIR etc. Epidemiological models starts with a given state and has probabilities of moving to another state. See: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidemic_model
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology